# .once() doesn't seem to work / recognized while working with Flutter & Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch some data from FireStore and store it in a local list to be displayed later in the form of cards. I have seen many tutorials where people have used `.once()` to fetch data.

Now, when I am trying to do the same then getting error like the word isn't recognized.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    CollectionReference dbRefItem = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("items");
    ***dbRefItem.once().then***
  }
```

[image]

I cant seem to find any documentation if it has been deprecated or am I doing something wrong! Hovering cursor on the error says

> "The method 'once' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
> a method named 'once'."

Comment: what does the linter say. Try hovering over the squiggly lines and paste the log here.

Comment: @uni: The method 'once' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'once'.

Comment: Have you added the Firebase core and firestore package in pubspec.yaml? Also, check if you've imported the firestore package above that dart file

Comment: Yes, its imported and in yaml as well. As per new documentation, core import isn't needed as it's a subset of other FireStore storage package but I have imported all anyway.

Comment: Not sure why that problem is still popping up, try restarting android studio and remove the .then() and if that still fails run flutter pub cache repair in the command line

Comment: I would start looking into `get` on [CollectionReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference-class.html) instead. If it solves your problem, then that's that.

Comment: @MichaelLee Would fetching via get and collection ref would do the same job as getting it once only?!

Comment: You would have to run `get` again to fetch the documents again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.get()` did the same job as `.once()`
However, `.once()` syntax is not being accepted by Flutter's latest SDK while worked on the previous one. Have raised a ticket with Flutter Dev forum.